# Matlab SQL update query

Tags: sql, database, matlab

So I have some data as follows:

var1
(time    value1)

```
2       1934
3       3221
4       1314
```

var2
(time    value2)

```
2       836
3       5364
4       2143
```

and I want to add it to a new table in a database which I have created containing the following fields: time, value1, value2.

Using the datainsert function of matlab I get the following (which is not what I want):

```
time    value1    value2
2       1934    
3       3221
4       1314
2                 836
3                 5364
4                 2143
```

Now I am trying to use the update function instead so I hopefully get the following:

```
time    value1    value2
2       1934      836
3       3221      5364
4       1314      2143
```

To get the time and value1 into the table I do the following:

```
 datainsert(connection,'table',{'time','value1'},var1);
```

but what should I do to now insert the value2 data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have time values for var1 and var2 identical (e.g. same values with same order)?

In this case you can simply create common array with three fields and insert this array into database:

```
new_var=[var1 var2(:,2)];
datainsert(connection,'table',{'time','value1','value2'},new_var);
```

If order of time values in not same for var1 and var2 than you will need more complex action to create common data set. For example, you can use intersection:

```
[new_time,i1,i2] = intersect(var1(:,1), var22(:,1));
new_var=[new_time var1(:,2) var2(:,2)];
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes the time values should be the same in both variables. The only reason there are separate variables for each is because I read them individually from the database in the first place. I will try your suggestion now :)